# List users connected to django-channels Group (channels 1.x)

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

So, I got as far as finding the `group_channels` function, but this doesn't seem to store user info. Example:

```
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
context['players_list'] = channel_layer.group_channels('lobby')
```

I get `{'players_list': ['daphne.response.WbZyUfNixL!sbzfJEzdPp', 'daphne.response.KfDHQnHLdw!DpoOqdGute', 'daphne.response.JqlcVVMuny!xHLDSaCzUz', 'daphne.response.mWrYVXDKoI!AjkyadSsPe']}` as a response.

How can I list users connected to Group('lobby')? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

You are in the right path to the solution, that is how it is actually done. Perhaps what you're missing is adding the proper procedures to the consumer, so it adds the required data.

In `django-channels` v.2.x the consumer includes this information automatically, but you have to add it manually in v.1.x, using for that a decorator or a proper declaration inside a Generic Consumer, as explained [in the documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/1.x/generics.html#sessions-and-users).

Comment: This does not answer my question

Comment: Not directly @maj because you don't provide your consumer. That's why I directed you to the section in the documentation where you can find how to edit your consumer to achieve it.